# Using inception v4 in retrain example

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to adapt the example retrain script ( https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py ) to use the Inception V4 model.

The script already supports the retraining of Inception V3 (2015) as well as different versions of Mobilenets.

What I've done so far:
Since the script uses protobuf (.pb) files and not checkpoints (.ckpt), I downloaded the `inception_v4.pb` from here: https://deepdetect.com/models/tf/inception_v4.pb. As far as I understand, one could also have loaded the checkpoint and used the freeze graph tool to obtain the same file.

Then, I viewed the graph in tensorboard using the tensorflow python tool `import_pb_to_tensorboard.py` which can be found in the tensorflow github repository. 
From there (correct me if I am not wrong) I found that the `resized_input_tensor_name` is called `InputImage` whereas the `bottleneck_tensor_name` is `InceptionV4/Logits/Logits/MatMul` with `bottleneck_tensor_size` is `1001`.

Having this information I tried to adapt the `create_model_info(architecture)` function of the retrain script by adding:

```
    elif architecture == 'inception_v4':
        data_url = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/image/imagenet/inception-2015-12-05.tgz' #this won't make any difference
        bottleneck_tensor_name = 'InceptionV4/Logits/Logits/MatMul'
        bottleneck_tensor_size = 1001
        input_width = 299
        input_height = 299
        input_depth = 3
        resized_input_tensor_name = 'InputImage'
        model_file_name = 'inception_v4.pb'
        input_mean = 128
        input_std = 128
```

I run the script using the following command:

```
python retrain.py --architecture=inception_v4 --bottleneck_dir=test2/bottlenecks --model_dir=inception_v4 --summaries_dir=test2/summaries/basic --output_graph=test2/graph_flowers.pb --output_labels=test2/labels_flowers.txt --image_dir=datasets/flowers/flower_photos --how_many_training_steps 100
```

and I am getting the following error:

> File "retrain.py", line 373, in create_bottleneck_file str(e)))
>   RuntimeError: Error during processing file datasets/flowers/flower_photos/tulips/4546299243_23cd58eb43.jpg (Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Can not convert a Operation into a Tensor.)

Comment: `data_url = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/image/imagenet/inception-2015-12-05.tgz'` does make a difference, `retrain.py` would interpret the filename of your model to `inception-2015-12-05.tgz`, so it would still use inception_v3 rather than inception_v4.

Comment: the download link is for inception v3, you need to find the download link for inception v4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm working through the same thing currently.

Try to add `:0` to the end of your `bottleneck_tensor_name` and your `resized_input_tensor_name`.

If you'll notice in [`retrain.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py), Google also uses this `:0` nomenclature.

My suspicion is that, for you, `InceptionV4/Logits/Logits/MatMul` is just an operation, which you're not trying to get for this script, while `InceptionV4/Logits/Logits/MatMul:0` is the first tensor instantiated from that operation, which you are trying to get for this script.

Answer (score 1):

Add this modification to your script then InputImage is viewed as a Tensor:

```
resized_input_tensor_name = 'InputImage:0'
```